# Passing a custom class as parameter to a loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, .net-assembly

I'm writing a clipboard/image uploading tool in C#, where a keycombo would e.g make a screenshot, then send the image to a **plugin** and then the plugin handles the uploading and returning of an URL.

Now, those plugins need to save settings, and those settings need to be editable inside my application, so I thought I'd use a data saving class I wrote a while ago, and pass a reference of an **initialized instance of that class** to the plugins.

The idea was to put that entire class into an include, which a plugin writer could just include in their project to handle the data, however despite both the plugin and main application using the exact same code, I get an error about the versions being different, namely this:

> {"[A]CedInc.Persistence.XMLPersistenceDictionary.savenode cannot be
>   cast to [B]CedInc.Persistence.XMLPersistenceDictionary.savenode. Type
>   A originates from 'CloudBoard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\git\CloudBoard\CloudBoard\bin\Debug\CloudBoard.exe'. Type B
>   originates from 'CloudBoard FTP upload plugin, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at
>   location
>   'C:\git\CloudBoard\CloudBoard\bin\Debug\plugins\CloudBoard FTP
>   upload plugin.dll'."}

My question is: Is it possible to pass an instance of a custom class to a plugin **without** having to put it in an assembly to be loaded by the plugin itself? and if so, how? Any idea/suggestion is welcome! I'm kinda stuck here.

Comment: Why not put that shared code/object it into a shared assembly?

Comment: @tcarvin because I prefer to not force any plugins onto potential plugin developers, even if just for sake of clean code, and to avoid 'inception' plugins.

Comment: Declaring the same class in two assemblies means you have *two different* types with the same name

Comment: @L.B Yea I realize that, and my question is, is it possible to pass a custom class WITHOUT shared assemblies?

Comment: Or more importantly, a reference to a custom class, as the variable has to be accessible by the application that loads the plugin.

Comment: Why don't you simply use  Xml serialization?

Comment: @L.B As the layout of the settings is more complicated than just saving it. The application needs to see exactly what is in the variable during runtime, and the plugin needs to see exactly what gets updated in the variable during runtime too. Therefore I'm passing an instance of that custom class to the plugins, so that the application handles both the setting storage AND can update the settings, as the user will be updating the settings through the application's GUI.

Comment: I got this to work perfectly fine with a shared assembly, which isn't really what I want, but I managed to get one thing fixed and that is that the assembly doesn't have to be present in the output directory of the plugin, as it's already loaded by the main application. So maybe I should just call a closeEnough.jpg. if anyone knows a way to do it without shared assemblies it'd be neat though!

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend a shared assembly version, you could alos supply your plugin authors a template code file with pre-defined class and method names.  And then you could use reflection to search the loaded assembly to locate the classes and methods matching your predefined signatures.  Once you find the methods, it is easy to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ttck9d7) them.

Answer (score 0):

You expect plugins not to reference any of your code at all?

In this case you may be able to find some interface in Framework assemblies that works to be passed to plugin instead of class. Maybe `IDictionary` or `IDictionary<string,string>` would work. This way plugin will not need to reference any of your assemblies for serialization and you will be able to pass you custom implementation. As side benefit for plugin authors will be much more convinient to unit-test their plugins (with concrete class form a random library it is much harder).